# How can make association with two different databases by factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Now I have two rails applications. The names are:

- App1
- App2

I want to do rspec test in App1. Also want to operate data in App2.

The model in App2:

```
# User
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

# Post
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The factory_girl files in App1:

```
# spec/factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => App2::User do
    name 'user_name'
  end
end

# spec/factories/posts.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post, :class => App2::Post do
    association :user, factory: :user
    name 'post_name'
  end
end
```

If I create data in spec file in App1:

```
# spec/my_test_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe MyTest do
  let(:app2_post) { create(:post) }
  ...
end
```

It said:

```
Failure/Error: let(:app2_post) { create(:post) }

NoMethodError:
  undefined method 'user=' for #<App2::Post:0x000000092933>
  Did you mean? user_id=
                user_id
...
```

The `:user` is not the class in App1 but in App2. If I tried `association App2::User, factory: :user`, also got error.

Then how to write the association here: `association :user, factory: :user`?